# How to handle URLs longer that 2048 chars in JSAPI v2.7 and ArcGIS 10.2

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-10.2, proxy

In ArcGIS Server 9.3 and JavaScript API v2.4 there was need to set proxy.config in ASP.NET in order to handle requests to REST map services having more than 2048 characters in the URL as parameters.

Is there any change in ArcGIS 10.2 and JS API v2.7 (or higher)?
How the URLs longer than 2048 characters are handled in ArcGIS Server 10.2?

Thanks.

Comment: Wondering if the WebAdaptor have something to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

the behavior of proxies supplied in the Esri JavaScript API resource center isn't controlled by ArcGIS Server or the JavaScript API itself in any way.  Rather, the ASP.NET proxy in particular is a pure C# implementation to follow cross origin resource sharing security rules when an application exposes services on another domain.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

in general its a better idea to troubleshoot and fix a proxy that isn't working than it is to try not to use it.